# Trigger email alert based on last row's condition NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I attempted to build a script but there are some issues. The table format are 2 columns which are date and values. These are the needs:

**IDEAL STATE**

1. Grab the last filled row (today's date) in the Google Sheets called "test".
2. Check in that row if the value in column F is greater than 0.5.
3. If it greater than 0.5, then trigger an email.
4. In email body, it should state "Results found on [date]."

This was my starting point but it does not produce what I want. These are the issues:

**CURRENT STATE**

1.The script grabs every row in which column F was greater than 0.5 in the past. I only want to check for today (which would be the last row). It should not look through everything in the past.

2.The email body states: Result found on [row number]". This makes no sense. I want the date to show, not the row number.

This is the current code. Please help.

```
function readCell() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");  
    var values = sheet.getRange("F3:F").getValues(); //this has the values
    var date = sheet.getRange("D3:D").getValues(); // this has the date

    var results = [];


    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){

      if(values[i]>=0.5)
      {
        results.push("Result found on:" +(i+3));  
      }

    }
    MailApp.sendEmail('blabla@gmail.com', 'Alert',     results.join("\n"));
};
```

Last Row in this context is Row 217, not 218, assuming sheet.getLastRow() would ignore #DIV/o! values. See screenshot for this.

[image]

**LATEST UPDATE**
The current Error is related "toDateString". I think it may be related that my Google Sheet is one day behind. So, it today is Jan 10, the last row in my Google Sheet is Jan 9th. I think that is why the error happens. Can you confirm? In that case, how do I change it to today-1 day?

See below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can check the last row:

```
function readCell() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var value = sheet.getRange('F' + lastRow).getValue();
    var date = sheet.getRange('D' + lastRow).getValue();

    if (value >= 0.5) {
      var result = 'Result found on: ' + date;
      MailApp.sendEmail('blabla@gmail.com', 'Alert', result);
    }
};
```

---

After seeing your data, I think the code below would suit you better.

```
function readCell() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
    var dates = sheet.getRange('D1:D').getValues();

    var date = null;
    var dateRow = 0;
    var dateCount = dates.length;
    var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    var yesterdayString = yesterday.toDateString();

    for (dateRow; dateRow < dateCount; ++dateCount) {

        date = dates[dateRow];

        if (date instanceof Date) {
            date = date.toDateString();

            if (date === yesterdayString) {
                ++dateRow;
                // To account for zero-based array
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    var value = sheet.getRange('F' + dateRow).getValue();

    if (value >= 0.5) {
      var result = 'Result found on: ' + date;
      MailApp.sendEmail('blabla@gmail.com', 'Alert', result);
    }
};
```

Comment: Just to confirm, last Row in this context is Row 217, not 218, assuming sheet.getLastRow() would ignore #DIV/o! values. See screenshot for this. I think with your script, it will look at Row 218, right?

Comment: Here is the documentation for [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

Comment: Have added another function which should suit you better. :)

Comment: The current Error is related "toDateString". I think it may be related that my Google Sheet is one day behind. So, if today is Jan 10, the last row in my Google Sheet is Jan 9th. I think that is why the error happens. Can you confirm? In that case, how do I change it to today-1 day? 
See screenshot attached.

Comment: Have made amendments to account for text in the date column and to work for yesterday.

Comment: Thank you so much. With the current code, it does NOT trigger an email though. I changed the cell value for 01/09/2019 from -.12 to 0.6 to test if the trigger works but I am not getting an alert email. I wonder why.

Comment: Set the debugger's stop point on the `if (value`... statement and see what the values are in the debugger window. :)

Comment: when i debug, the same happens what I posted on the last screenshot. It looks like var value and var result are undefined.

Comment: You stopped the debugger on the second if statement not the first, yeah?

Comment: Update: When i clicked in "Run function" in the menu. When I run the function, it takes forever and at some point it stops executing. I added a screenshot to show the data. I only have 219 rows so far in time. Does it take the fct so long due to the loop?

Comment: Hmmm. Have updated my answer. Let me know if you're still getting an error.

Comment: It still takes too long. Can you try not making the script so loop-intensive? It goes through all rows for the entire Google Sheet looks like. How to make it more performant?

Comment: It only loops through until it finds yesterday. That's what `break` is for. This is not a free code-writing website, I won't write it for you.